# Javascript check the address path link is available or not

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

```html
<script>
  function doSomethingIfFound(url, status) {
    alert(url + " was found, status" + status);
  }

  function doSomethingIfNotFound(url, status) {
    alert(url + " was not found, status" + status);
  }

  function test(url) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        doSomethingIfFound(url, xhttp.status);
      } else if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status != 200) {
        doSomethingIfNotFound(url, xhttp.status);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }


  test('https://test.e-cover.com.my/')
  test('https://www.e-cover.com.my/')
  test('http://www.mypolicy.com.my/mypolicy/login.jsp/')
  test('https://itdidnotexistwhenitrieitiswear.museum/')
</script>
```

I have no idea why my code detect some url links are available and some are not available although the so called "not available" are available. Please help, thanks.

```html
<script>
  function checkURL(url) {
    var scriptTag = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script"));
    scriptTag.onload = function() {
      alert(url + " is available");
    };
    scriptTag.onerror = function() {
      alert(url + " is not available");
    };
    scriptTag.src = url;
  }
</script>

<body>

  link 1 available site detected as available (correct output) :
  <input type="radio" name="link" onclick="checkURL('https://www.e-cover.com.my/');">
  <br/>link 2 available site but detected as not available :
  <input type="radio" name="link" onclick="checkURL('https://test.e-cover.com.my/');">
  <br/>link 3 available site but detected as not available :
  <input type="radio" name="link" onclick="checkURL('http://www.mypolicy.com.my/mypolicy/login.jsp/');">
  <br/>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is neat but you cannot do it that way, you need to do it properly, sorry. Just do an AJAX request and ignore the return, just check the HTTP codes.

```
function doSomethingIfFound(url, status){
  console.log(url + " was found, status" + status);
}
function doSomethingIfNotFound(url, status){
  console.log(url + " was not found, status" + status);
}
function test(url) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      doSomethingIfFound(url, xhttp.status);
    } else if ( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status != 200 ){
      doSomethingIfNotFound(url, xhttp.status);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}


test("https://test.e-cover.com.my/")
test("https://www.e-cover.com.my/")
test("http://www.mypolicy.com.my/mypolicy/login.jsp/")
test("https://itdidnotexistwhenitrieitiswear.museum/")
```

gives the results

"https://test.e-cover.com.my/ was found, status 200" 
"https://itdidnotexistwhenitrieitiswear.museum/ was not found, status 0" 
"https://www.e-cover.com.my/ was found, status 200" 
"http://www.mypolicy.com.my/mypolicy/login.jsp/ was not found, status 404"

So, if the url does not exists at all, the request returns `0`, `404` if the site exists but has not the page you want and `200` if all is ok and proper.

If that still doesn't work for you, you need to be a bit more precise in the details.

Comment: hmm .. wondering how is it work .. please check this fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/ce3Lttjc/  .. im applying the solution you gave

Comment: Works correctly. The last adress (the one with the login) gave an error, you might check the HTTP number and include it. My snippet checks only for 200 which means something in the line of "no fault, all ok". You might pass `url` to the functions `doSomethingIfFound` and to `doSomethingIfNotFound` the `xhttp.status` too, to see exactly what happend. The alert was just a placeholder, you should use `console.log` instead.

Comment: i'm sorry, i still dont get it ..perhaps can you provide me an example how it's work on these 3 url?  i alert the status it return 0 for and go for `doSomethingIfNotFound();` that's mean the url is not available right?

Comment: Hi, may i know how did you get the result 200 ?? i use the example you gave.. i keep get status = 0 for these 4 url links.. question updated..

Comment: @user3835327 I got the results by: open the scratchpad of Firefox (here: version 43.0) by alt+F4. Switch the environment to browser (environment->browser). Copy and Paste (with ctrl+c and ctrl+v or from the menue, does not work in another way per default) my code without anything extra into the scartchpad. Open the console with ctrl+shift+j. Click into the scratchpad and hit ctrl+r. Check the console for output. How did you do it?

Comment: Thank for guiding @deamentiaemundi .. i got the status by using the method you provided.. but  how can i apply this in my system? when i put the code in my my system and run local testing.. i'll often get status 0.. may i know how to overcome this problem ?

Comment: What *is* your system? Please elaborate.

Comment: Im running rational application developer .. normal eclipse program to run the html ..

Comment: @user3835327 probably because of a too restrictive sandbox. You may ask another question regarding that specific problem like e.g.: "the following code works in a browser but not in r.a.d version xyz and eclipse version abc" (filll in your version numbers).